# Word or two-word string to represent a number of times an action is done

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that means "the number of times an action is done".

For example, I am going to express "Number of times that this report has been printed" but I want it to be shorter. Shorter here I mean very short -- like 2 word or less short.

What I have in mind right now are

1. Times Printed
2. Print Count

but I am open for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you think that the large demand of single-words might be connected with phenomenon of character limits?  If so, the shortening of words such as that suggested by Xanne (below) would be ideal, even where they are not to be found in a dictionary.

Comment: **copy count** corresponds to your definition.

Comment: Or the generic **times done**. But that doesn't sound particularly highfalutin or technical.

Answer (score 2):

In the area of training (for a sporting event, perhaps) the term is *reps,* short for repetitions:

> rep noun (EXERCISE) (usually plural)

> used for saying the number of times that a particular exercise should be repeated in a sports workout. Rep is short for repetition https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rep?q=reps

In publishing, successive print runs are called *printings.*

The US publishing convention is to print, on the publication data page, the numbers from 1 to 10 in reverse order. For each printing after the first, the rightmost number is deleted, so the series shows the number of the printing. The words “Second Printing” or whatever number is appropriate often appear.

The word *iterations* also refers the number repetitions of a series of events.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of printing, you are referring to the **print run**

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/print-run).
> *Print run*
> the number of copies of a particular book, newspaper, etc. that are produced at one time

Outside printing, the phrase does not have general applicability.